# Looking for Highcharts similar to the attachment

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for chart like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-B1S_skFx0HR29ZNG1sV0pfWk0/view?usp=sharing) in highcharts. Can any one help to find chart like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-B1S_skFx0HR29ZNG1sV0pfWk0/view?usp=sharing). I really needed but I am not able to make similar chart of my own in highcharts.

```
UPDATE:
```

I got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/otm0oq2c/3/) one in the internet.

Comment: I don't know why someone have down voted. I just asked for help.!

Comment: Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/exkLseoj/. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how to customize [legend](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend)

```
 legend: {
  align: 'right',
  verticalAlign: 'top',
  layout: 'vertical',
  x: 0, 
  y: 100, //distance from top
  padding: 3,
  itemMarginTop: 5,  
  itemMarginBottom: 5,
  useHTML: true, //now you can customize label with various kind of styling
  labelFormatter: function() {

    return '<div style="width:100px;"><span style="float:left; margin-left:10px">' + names[this.index - 1] + '</span><span style="float:right">' + values[this.index - 1] + '</span></div>';
  },
  symbolRadius: 0, //square symbols
},
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply, @Deep. Thanks for your update. I would like to know if we can center align every bar to its corresponding x axis period just like the original image.

Comment: Hi @Deep, I have found the solution for center aligning every bar to its corresponding xaxis and I have updated in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/1/). Just add groupPadding: 0.5 to the first series.

Comment: hi got your solution.

Comment: looks good @Deep.. Great Job.. Once again thanks for helping me in this issue.

Comment: Hi, @Deep, I have another question. Please take a look at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/3/). Here, the green bar doesn't display any value. I know adding overflow:"none", crop:false will display the value. But It  goes out of plotting area, sometimes for larger numbers it overlaps title. I would like to get green bar value(ONLY) inside the bar instead of hidding the value.

Comment: Please use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678049/how-to-fix-hidden-datalabel-in-highcharts) to answer.

Comment: Please use have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679142/how-to-add-extra-tearsticks-in-highcharts) too. @Deep

Comment: Hi deep, can you please help me to solve this problem. Please look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750623/how-to-prevent-bars-overlapping-eachother-in-highcharts).