# How to fix hidden dataLabel in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

Please take a look at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/3/). Here, the green bar doesn't display any value. I know adding `overflow:"none", crop:false` will display the value. But it goes out of plotting area, sometimes for larger numbers it overlaps title. I would like to get green bar value (ONLY) inside the bar instead of hiding the value.

Comment: The combination of your `rotation: -90`, and the `align: 'left'` seems to thwart the default behavior - the default is to behave exactly like you're asking. While I don't have a solution to that specific problem, I have to ask - why would you want to rotate the labels anyway?? Makes them harder to read, and introduces a problem that won't exist otherwise. FWIW, I would suggest simply keeping the labels at `0` rotation and fix two problems at once :)

Comment: Seriously I need this feature. I have enabled both horizontal and vertical view of dataLabels for charts in my project. If you can find a way to help me, it will be so nice. @jlbriggs

Comment: Set the inside property with true value for a green column. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d7a49u1L/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For particular column (i.e green column) label value to be inside, you can add attribute `inside: true` in data .Refer [dataLabels.inside](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels.inside) for more info

```
 series: [{
    color: colors[0],
    showInLegend: false,
     data: [{
     ....//first value
     , {
      y: 3500,
      name: 'Second',
      color: colors[1],
      dataLabels: {
        inside: true //labels  will be inside column
      }
    },... // third and remaining
   });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1g2cq4d/) demonstration