# How to add extra tears(ticks) in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

```
HIGH CHARTS
```

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678049/how-to-fix-hidden-datalabel-in-highcharts) question, I would like to ask another question here in this thread.

How to add extra tears(ticks), in such a way, the green bar dataLabel, does stay inside plotting area, rather, going out of plotting area or made hidden. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/3/)

Comment: I didn't  understand _How to add extra tears(ticks)_

Comment: This is not a proper way but still works. Set cart height . check http://jsfiddle.net/qr9xrLdj/

Comment: Looked at your update. I cannot change the height of chart. I am dynamically generating values, and it keeps on changing. I could not change height every time. If you can suggest me any other idea please? @Deep3015

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. But quickest one is adding a max value to yAxis with using [yAxis.max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max).

```
yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        max: 6000
    },
```

Here is the working example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/4/)**.

**OR**

You can use the combination of [yAxis.tickAmount](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount) and [yAxis.tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval) like this;

```
yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        tickAmount: 10,
        tickInterval: 1000
    },
```

Here is the working example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/5/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting a new max property or trying a different combination of ticks, you can simply set `overflow` property with 'none' value and `crop` with false. This way you can display data labels outside the plot area.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.crop

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2qtpx0rL/