# How to prevent bars overlapping eachother in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

```
HIGH CHARTS
```

Please look at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcbnbso/9/). Here the bars overlap each other. How to prevent this by resizing the bar width dynamically.

Comment: Or you may use scroll bar http://jsfiddle.net/qpus6b6q/ .see [blogs](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If happens because you set bar width with fixed value. If you want bars to take all available place for width, instead of using `pointWidth`, set `pointPadding` to 0, `groupPadding` to 0 and `borderWidth` to 0.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.pointPadding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.groupPadding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.borderWidth

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yek6g5vy/

Comment: Thank you @d_paul. Your example works in the same way as I expected. I have done some update like changing pointPadding and it worked exactly to my need. If you like to see what I modified see them [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yek6g5vy/1/).

Comment: @JeffrinJohn No problem, glad it helped you. Using pointPadding is convenient.

Comment: can you help me in this issue paul?. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067813/how-to-get-height-of-individual-bars-in-column-chart-of-highcharts @d_paul

Comment: Hi Paul, can you help me in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221064/how-to-do-multi-level-pie-chart-in-highcharts) issue.

Answer (score 1):

If possible remove container inline css height.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6r5buxe/)  Demo

Or you can use scrollbar using highstock.js

```
 xAxis: {
  categories: ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh'],
  allowDecimals: false,
  min: 0,
  max: 4,
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
  },
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpus6b6q/) demo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions deep. But I can use neither of the two suggestions. If you find a way to adjust the bar width dynamically, just like column chart works, please suggest me. Thanks for your time deep. :-)

Comment: Hi @deep, d_paul solution worked for me. Thanks again for your help. :-)

Comment: Hi deep, can you help me in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221064/how-to-do-multi-level-pie-chart-in-highcharts) issue.