# How to get height of individual bars in column chart of highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

Is there a way to find individual bar height? I know chart.plotHeight would return potting area height. Similarly i would like to know individual bar height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all point's shape arguments in `Point.shapeArgs` object. Take a look at the example below.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gL9e7mbj/

Comment: Thank you so much paul. Got exactly how I wanted. I also did an update in your answer. It was pointShapeArgs.height for pointShapeArgs.width.  [Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9e7mbj/1/). Very small update. :-)

Comment: No Problem Paul. :-) @d_paul

Comment: Hi! Got a problem ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250112/how-to-make-the-legend-come-in-the-image-in-highcharts ) @d_paul