# How to make the legend come in the image in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

```
How?
```

How to make the legend come in the image while exporting chart as png image?

Please refer [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts is designed for export only chart. If you want to export also elements outside the chart, you can use for example `html2canvas`. Take a look at the example posted below.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/h96daj1k/